# How could an offline app store images so that they aren't trivially discoverable?

Tags: android

There is an app I play which has lots of images. I have reverse engineered the app but couldn't find the images in the APK. The app is an offline app so it doesnt retrieve images from a server.

My question is, then, where did this app store its images? I'd like to achieve the same level of protection (to deter casual observation of the images).

Comment: Can you confirm if you've ruled out any of the following: being stored elsewhere in some other file after maybe being downloaded to your phones memory, being dynamically generated by the application itself?

Comment: Perhaps you could be less generic and tell us what app you are talking about. Someone might know

Comment: Questions about how a specific product accomplished a task are off-topic though; I think this question is fine in this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download the images once, at first launch, as theorized in the comments. Or encrypt them locally with a key that is sent over the internet. Both of these options would require an internet connection at least *once* though. If you want to store your image data in a fashion that isn't trivially discoverable, but also does not require an internet connection *ever*, you have a few possibilities:

- Store the images in code. This means either write code to generate the image (as @Water suggested in the comments), or store the actual byte buffer of the image file in a global or static variable some place in your game's executable. Images that are completely procedurally generated (the first variant) won't really be discoverable at all. Images that are stored as buffers in code probably won't be found by programs that just unpack all the bundled files in the APK, but they may be found by programs that scan the entire application archive for patterns that look like potential known image file formats.
- "Encrypt" (or more reasonably "obfuscate") the files so that they can't be trivially read. You could simply flip every other byte of the image, which would likely make it look like garbage when opened. This technique was employed by a game of my childhood, [TaskMaker](http://www.robotroom.com/StormImpact.html); they compressed the picture resources that stored all the game graphics with a custom algorithm that was sufficient to render them unreadable by most basic resource-editing tools of the era. This technique will hide the contents of the image but may not hide the fact that the images exist.

You can of course combine these techniques for maximum impact. Because the data is still there, and the method to correctly access the data is still there, neither of these techniques can make it *impossible* to find the image data, but they can make it so most people who are just casually poking around won't find anything you don't want them to see, probably.